# How can I concatenate a bunch of numbers with commas, without adding a trailing comma?

Tags: java

```
PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
    new FileWriter("numbers.dat")
)); 
for(int i = start; i <= 100; i = i + 2) { 
    fout.print(i + ", "); 
}
```

Right now my output is like this:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10,
```

What I want:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a neat way of doing it:

```
PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
    new FileWriter("numbers.dat")
)); 

String sep = "";
for(int i = start; i <= 100; i += 2) { 
    fout.print(sep + i);
    sep = ", ";
}
```

Here's another way:

```
PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
    new FileWriter("numbers.dat")
)); 

for(int i = start; i <= 100; i += 2) { 
    fout.print((i == start ? "" : ", ") + i);
}
```

---

Without being too sure of the function of `PrintWriter`, it may be more efficient to produce the string with a [`StringBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) first:

```
PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
    new FileWriter("numbers.dat")
));

StringBuffer buffer;

for(int i = start; i <= 100; i += 2) { 
    buffer.append(i == start ? "" : ", ").append(i);
}

fout.print(buffer);
```

Or more efficiently still:

```
PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
    new FileWriter("numbers.dat")
));

StringBuffer buffer;

for(int i = start; i <= 100; i += 2) { 
    buffer.append(i).append(", ");
}

buffer.setLength(buffer.length()-1);

fout.print(buffer);
```

Comment: I figured that once I'd started, I may as well finish

Answer (score 2):

Print the first number and then print "," + number afterwards. Starting from i = start + 2;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("numbers.dat"))); 
 for(int i = start; i <= 100; i += 2)    { 
     if(i + 2 <= 100)  
        fout.print(i+","); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like -

```
fout.print(i);
if (i < 100) {
    fout.print(",");
}
```

Or write to a StringBuffer and delete trailing comma after the loop

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(...){
...
}

sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() -1);
fout.print(sb.toString());
```

Hope this helps!